# UISplitViewController - hiding master view in iPad landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, landscape

I'm using the iOS SDK 8.1.

In landscape mode, is it possible to make the master view animate left to hide and then animate right to display again? I don't want it to overlap the detail view like in portrait mode.

Would I have to create my own custom split view controller for that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to hide/unhide master in landscape mode.
There are many opensource libraries for creating custom splitView controller available.
This is one good library : https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController